# Compare multiple strings in textview of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to compare all the strings entered in a textview of iphone. Once the user finishes with typing in textview I want to compare strings entered by the user.

How do I do it?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you define "finishes with typing", here is my guess:

You have to set up your class become UITextViewDelegate and implements some methods:

- If you want to get the text whenever the text changes, use:

`- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`

- If you want to get the text whenever the text view resign first responder, use:

`- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

I also don't know what you define by comparing all the NSString. One way to do is put them into `NSSet` and `NSSet` itself will remove duplicates of `NSString` for you

Comment: textViewDidChange & textViewDidEndEditing, none of the methods are getting activated.. please help. Trying out with NSSet

Comment: do you have this line of code : `self.textView.delegate = self`

Comment: hey Thanks...silly mistake by a beginer..for textViewDidEndEditing do I need to handle keyboard dismiss event?

Comment: then how the textViewDidEndEditing will be activated? i mean if we hav cursor still in textview? Return key will add new line to textview

Comment: oh, you mean that if your cursor still in text view. Even if you handle keyboard dismiss event, we cannot handle the return key, right, it is just add new line and don't dismiss the keyboard.